# BMO2 2011/12 question on cyclic quadrilateral and showing two circumcircles have same radius

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

This problem is from the [2011/12 BMO2](https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/home/bmo2-2012.pdf).

> The diagonals AC and BD of a cyclic quadrilateral meet at E. The
> midpoints of the sides AB, BC, CD and DA are P, Q, R and S
> respectively. Prove that the circles EPS and EQR have the same
> radius.

I can't seem to find anything meaningful to work with. Would the approach be to prove that $\triangle{EPS}$ AND $\triangle{EQR}$ are congruent? I've found that PQRS is a parallelogram but I don't really know where to go from there. Please could someone provide me with a hint or starting point?

Comment: According to a Chinese proverb, an image says more than a thousand words :-)

Comment: Two triangles $EPS$ and $EQR$ are not congruent. In fact, there are no congruent pairs of triangles in this configuration. However, there are quite a few pairs of similar triangles. We suggest you to try to use them to find a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the diagram below, you can follow these steps:

Step $1$: $\triangle EBC$ and $\triangle EAD$ are similar. So, $\angle QEC= \angle SED.$

Step $2$: Similarly, you should be able to show that: $\angle PEA =\angle RED.$

Step $3$: $\angle QEP +\angle RES =180^{\circ} \implies \sin \angle QEP =\sin \angle RES. $

Step $4$: $|PQ|=|RS|=\frac{1}{2}|AC|.$

Step $5$: Now, by [the law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), it follows that $\triangle EQP$ and $\triangle ERS$ have the same circumradius.

[image]

Comment: I've just realized I proved a similar claim for $\triangle PQE$ and $\triangle ERS$ while you asked about $\triangle PES$ and $\triangle EQR$. However, there is no difference. you can simply apply the very same approach to prove the main claim.